# RecyclerView in CardView item removal weird animation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, cardview

I did some research and found no relevant information, though it seems like a common use-case.

I have a recycler view, which contains items with the following layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/groups_card_view"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/standard_card_corner_radius"
    app:contentPadding="@dimen/inner_card_content_padding"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/outer_card_background"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        ...some childs...

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/words_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

So basically what matters it that item of one RecyclerView contains another RecyclerView inside CardView.

At some point i want to remove an item from that inner RecyclerView with standard removal animation, which i aim to achieve this way:

```
class WordsRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private List<String> wordsToTrack;

    ...basic adapter code...

    class WordsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ...basic holder code...

        @OnClick(R.id.img_btn_delete)
        public void deleteButtonOnClick() {
            wordsToTrack.remove(getAdapterPosition());
            notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

Item removes, it works fine, except... CardView which wraps the inner RecyclerView shrinks right when item was removed, so animation of item's removal looks like on the following gif:

[image]

So the question is - how to make it work with proper animation?

Comment: can you post the animation code ?

Comment: Try adding android:animateLayoutChanges="true" to your groups_card_view

Comment: @KrzyShzy Didn't work.

Comment: @AalapPatel it's default recycler view animation, the lines that are used to trigger it are posted.

Comment: Try giving the recyclerview inside the group_cardview a fixed height of 273 dp.

Comment: @KrzyShzy Thank you for participation, but it's obvious that fixed height would solve the problem as CardView would not shrink on item's removal. The question i asked assumes keeping that animation, as it is needed.